# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.25.1 - Django application running on docker

Tags: python, nginx, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have dockerized my Django application, and below is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .        
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web


volumes:
  static:
```

and the nginx file is:

```
upstream prod {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://prod;     
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

whenever I am making an API request, the request data is getting stored correctly in the database but then after that I am getting.

I have used gunicorn and nginx. How can I resolve this?

I've also tried tried changing the proxy_pass to `http://web:8000`, but this also doesn't works.

Comment: Have you checked your backend logs? That error typically means that the backend server did not return a valid http response.